# Arrowfunction inside of Object

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

**Edit** like suggested from str:

I want to create an object in a panel, and this object should contain a (or two) function(s). This Object will be handed over to a component (I am programming with angularjs, so I will hand it over via bindings) so I can configure my panel on the "clientcomponent" that opens that panel...

If I am trying to do that, IntelliJ gives the Error warning that a ',' is expected

---

I am trying to incorporate an arrowfunction inside of an js object.. but intellij doesn't like my approach.

I'm searching for sth like this:

```
this.api = {
        showContent=(this.config)=> {
          //do sth
    }
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Maybe you should explain in words what you are trying to do. Your code example is just invalid and not clear at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS Object structure:

```
this.api = {
    showContent: true
};
```

Now to add [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) try this

```
this.api = {
    showContent: config => {
        return true;
    }
};
```

Similar to old style

```
this.api = {
    showContent: function (config) {
        return true;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Tried that, this.config doesn't work. But it works with 'showConntent: config =>' I would upvote, but the downvote of my question prevents that... thanks for your answer!

Comment: Keep in mind, when having 0 or more than 1 parameter, parenthesis are required. so: `showContent: () => {` and `showContent: (a, b) => {`. Other than that, great answer!

Comment: `this.config` is not a valid parameter name.